# how to create an icon for my python application

Tags: python

I wrote a program in Python, then created a GUI using Tkinter. When I use programs on my computer (like Microsoft Word), I don't need to access the GUI from the command line I just click the application icon.

How do I put my program (the program itself is in the same .py file as the GUI) into an application icon that will start my program?

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Windows, you can create a shortcut. Or you can just put your `.py` file on your desktop.

If you want to make an `.exe` file I would suggest installing `py2exe`. I've compiled Tkinter Python scripts into `.exe`s with `py2exe` many  times.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create an executable file (`.exe`) to do that. I would suggest using something like `pyinstaller` or `py2exe` to do that.

What's more, you can use that executable on other computers that do not have python installed!

Take a look at the documentation of these:

http://www.pyinstaller.org/

http://www.py2exe.org/

**EDIT-** pyinstaller can create stand-alone executables under Windows, Linux, Mac OS X, Solaris and AIX.